# I have 2 WFE and 2 APP and DB in Cluster

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, iis, minrole

I have 2 WFE and 2 APP and DB in Cluster.When I create web application in all the servers web application and application pool gets created?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will created on all servers but only WFE will be serving the content for the end users. Because your DNS will point to the WFEs not APP servers.

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application is running on APP thats why SP created the web app on app server.

[Check this article for more about MinRole services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/description-of-minrole-and-associated-services-in-sharepoint-server-2016).